# onPress for button is not working when pressed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state

```
<TouchableOpacity style ={styles.resetButton} 
     onPress = {console.log(this.state.working_pressure)}>
     <Text style ={styles.loginButtonText}>RESET</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

I am using a touchable opacity with the code seen above. When I change the state `working_pressure` but do not press the button, the console logs the state. The problem is that when the button is pressed, nothing is logged at all.

My end goal is to make the button reset the input text so that all fields are reset to blank. With this issue I cannot get it to work.

If you have any ideas that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onPress` prop should be given a function it should call when the `TouchableOpacity` is pressed. You are currently *invoking* `console.log` straight away on render.

You could e.g. create a new inline arrow function instead:

```
<TouchableOpacity
  style={styles.resetButton} 
  onPress={() => console.log(this.state.working_pressure)}
>
  <Text style={styles.loginButtonText}>RESET</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: If I wanted to invoke a function would I do                    
onPress={() => this.reset}
>

Comment: @paulgio You don't want to invoke it directly on render, but give a function reference. You could write `() => this.reset()`, or even just `this.reset`.

Comment: It still will not invoke my function. My function is:                         reset(){
    this.setState = {
      working_pressure: '',
    }
  }          When I press the button, the value of work_pressure is unchanged.

Comment: You have to bind the `reset` method to `this`, or make it into an arrow function. `setState` is also a function you call, not something you assign a value to. E.g. `reset = () => { this.setState({ working_pressure: '' }); }`

Comment: Got it to work somewhat by doing onPress={() => this.setState({ working_pressure: '' }). The text in the textInput that I have still does not physically reset when the  button is pressed though. Is there anyway to have the text in the textInput reset as well?

Comment: @paulgio You have to make it [controlled by setting the `value` with the state variable](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#value). E.g. `<TextInput value={this.state.working_pressure} />`

Comment: <TextInput
        placeholder = 'bar'
        style = {{fontSize:20, height: 40, paddingLeft: 20, lineHeight: 20}}
        value = {this.state.working_pressure}
        autoCapitalize = 'none'
        /> .                                                                           
 For some reason it still displays the original text when the reset button is pressed even though the state is reset.

Comment: @paulgio Hard to say without seeing the entire component. It might be worth opening up another question if you can't figure out what's wrong.